# Handling Daylight Saving Time for scheduling purposes

Tags: date, datetime, utc, dst

I am working with an API that generates time periods based on a configured set of parameters.

So for example, I can specify I want 12 one month periods starting Jan 1st at midnight, and therefore the API will generate 12 monthly periods

```
01 Jan 2016 00:00:00 – 31 Jan 2016 23:59:59
01 Feb 2016 00:00:00 – 28 Feb 2016 23:59:59
Through to
01 Dec 2016 00:00:00 – 31 Dec  2016 23:59:59
```

Now the API expects a start date param supplied for the sequence of periods to be an ISO formatted string in UTC. So I’m currently in the UK, therefore if I choose to start the monthly periods from Jan 1st 2016 this would be `2016-01-01T00:00:00Z` and is what I supply to the API call I am making to say when the first instance of my monthly periods should begin.

So now if I view the start and end dates of the generated monthly periods via the API, I will see them come back as

```
2016-01-01T00:00:00Z - 2016-01-31T23:59:59Z
2016-02-01T00:00:00Z - 2016-02-28T23:59:59Z
Etc to
2016-12-01T00:00:00Z - 2016-12-31T23:59:59Z
```

Something struck me about these generated periods and that is I want them to begin at midnight for where I currently am, but a period that is affected by GMT Daylight Time, so say my April period will look like so in the generated period from the API

```
2016-04-01T00:00:00Z - 2016-04-30T23:59:59Z
```

Parsing the start date for the above into a date object for viewing in the client (on my machine) will show up as

```
Fri Apr 01 2016 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
```

So it’s saying that period starts at 1am and not midnight.
Now say if I wanted 12 months to be generated from 1st Jun when Daylight Savings is in effect.

My client side code currently will supply a start date to the API of `2016-05-31T23:00:00Z`. This causes the API to generate start dates for each monthly period as being

```
2016-05-31T23:00:00Z - 2016-06-31T22:59:59Z (June Period)
2016-06-31T23:00:00Z - 2016-07-31T22:59:59Z (July)
Etc to
2017-04-30T23:00:00Z - 2017-05-31T22:59:59Z (May)
```

But now for a period  that is not in GMT Daylight Time, so Jan for example it will show up as

```
2016-12-31T23:00:00Z - 2017-01-31T22:59:59Z
```

Meaning my client will see that start date as

```
Sat Dec 31 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
```

So not Jan 1st at 00:00

Does this suggest that the API should know about the users timezone so the period generation logic in the API can factor this is when calculating the start and end dates?

Maybe I'm over thinking things here?!

Comment: What are the time periods used for? Personally I would just stick with using UTC(GMT) and have done with it. Removes all the confusion.

Comment: They are used to allocate events that occur during these generated periods.

Comment: Does these events require daylight savings to be accounted for?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure to be honest, I will need to check with the team who wrote the API. I guess if the answer is no, then as you say, using UTC throughout will remove any confusion

Comment: That is especially true if you are trying to collect statistics. I remember my manager being please in October as usage had an extra hour! But sad in March.

Comment: FYI - There's no such thing as "GMT Daylight Time".  That's a Microsoft invented term.  In real life it's usually referred to as "British Summer Time".

Comment: @MattJohnson: Where does Microsoft refer to "GMT Daylight Time"?

Comment: @KeithThompson - Windows Registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\GMT Standard Time\Dlt` (on an English language PC), and of course in APIs that use it, such as `TimeZoneInfo.DaylightName` in .NET.  In the OP's usage, I'd guess perhaps JavaScript in Internet Explorer via `new Date().toString()`.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Great. So someone at Microsoft didn't know what GMT actually means.

Comment: Sort of, but it's a bit more complicated than that and goes back to early legacy of Windows.  There are lots of other examples.  You can see some of them in [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), and [on my blog](http://codeofmatt.com/2014/04/07/working-with-time-zone-names-in-net/).

Answer (score 0):

The only real question I see here is:

> Does this suggest that the API should know about the users timezone so the period generation logic in the API can factor this is when calculating the start and end dates?

In general, the answer is **YES**.  Any time you are mapping calendar dates back to specific instants in time, then by definition you must involve time zones.  That time zone can be that of the user's, or of some specific business location, or fixed to UTC, but they indeed part of the logic.

Consider that not every calendar date *has* a valid local "midnight" in every time zone.  An example is 2015-10-18 in Sao Paulo Brazil, where the first moment of that day was 1:00 AM due to their spring-forward daylight saving time transition.  There are many other examples of this around the world.

The only way to avoid the problem entirely is to not deal in specific times.  If you are only working with whole dates, then your code can certainly compute the exact dates of each month without knowing anything about time zones.  `2016-01-01` through `2016-01-31` has no awareness of time or time zone.  It's only when you try to ask what the *current* date is, or if *now* is within that range, or if some other specific *instant* in time is within that range that you have to start thinking about time zones.